# UILocalNotification presentNotificationNow Issue

Tags: ios, mkmapview, uilocalnotification, clregion

this issue has been driving me crazy. What I am trying to do is trigger a notification when the user enter in a region. However, what I want is, if the user is using the app show an alert message and if the app is in background shows a local notification.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

    if (app.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive)
    {
        NSURL *musicFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Alarm" ofType:@"caf"]];
        AVAudioPlayer *audioFile = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] init];
        audioFile = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:musicFile error:NULL];
        [audioFile play];

        UIAlertView *arrivingDestinationAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Arriving" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Alert"]  delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [arrivingDestinationAlert show];
    }else if(app.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground || app.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive)
    {
        UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        notification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d to reach your destination", self.distToRemind];
        notification.alertAction = @"Destination Approaching";
        notification.hasAction = YES;
        notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
        [app presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
    }

    [manager stopMonitoringForRegion:region];
}
```

What I was doing before was working. Which was lunch an local notification without asking whether the state of the app was background or active. I was just lunching the notification as soon the `didEnterRegion` was trigger. However now I can get it work.

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are checking for the active state in the wrong spot. I do something very similar, but I check for active state in the AppDelegate when the notification fires. You should intercept the local notification in `-didReceiveLocalNotification`. If the state is active, push your UIAlertView there. If you fire the alert from the -didEnterRegion or -didExitRegion from the background, it will never be seen.